# How to validate file type in java

Tags: java

I have created a text file with some content. I changed its extension to .xlsx.
I used this code to validate file-

```
String filepath = "C:\\Users\\prabhat.sameer\\Desktop\\test.xlsx";
File f = new File(filepath);
String mimetype= new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
String type = mimetype.split("/")[0];
System.out.println("type " + type);
if (type.equals("text")) {
    System.out.println("It's an text file");
} else {
    System.out.println("It's NOT an text file");
}
```

Its content type also changed with change of extension. How to validate this?

Comment: File name (including extension) has nothing to do with its content. Which are you trying to validate?

Comment: I want to validate my file type. I want to reject those files whose extension are changed intensionally for security purpose.

Comment: So as @jay posted in his answer you need some libraries to do this. You generally want to check whether given sequence of bytes meets a certain specification (such as `xlsx`).

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file by double-clicking on it, are you able to read the data?  Usually a special library like POI is required to write to excel so I would be surprised if it does.
If your txt file has data in csv(comma separated) format, then changing the extension to .csv should work for you.